# Can I use a Block inside an Include file?

Tags: templating, include, blocks

I have a _layout.html template which has both an include partial `{% include '_partials/_header.html' %}` and a block section (e.g. Content) for other templates to extend it.

Can I put another block section (e.g. Breadcrumb) inside the include file and use that in a template which extends _layout.html? So far it doesn't seem to work. If I move the Breadcrumb block from the include template into _layout.html it works fine, and when I move it back the content in the template extension does not show.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code as a twig fiddle at http://twigfiddle.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is possible @jack. Take a look at this working demo - http://twigfiddle.com/9rwjeo

---

Update:

On closer inspection the original example did not work. You can not have a block inside an include how you are describing.

I have update the twig fiddle with a work around though

Comment: Thanks @Fyrebase. Apologies for my deleted comments as I was working off older versions of this page and the Twigfiddle example. So, yes, you have confirmed my finding. Thanks for the workaround - I haven't tried it yet in my code but I'm pretty sure it will do the job based on your demo. It is a pity because I like the include model for structuring my twig code - I find it cleaner than using blocks which I prefer for smaller bits of code. Perhaps I can get the workaround to fit my style. I didn't know about Twigfiddle, so that is a useful bit of info for me too. Thanks.

Comment: Update: Yes it worked in my code. I just needed to add a |raw filter to deal with the HTML :)

Comment: It's also worth noting that blocks don't work in the reverse either - you cannot define a block in the main template and override it inside an include. So as a general rule:  **don't use the {% block %} tag inside an include file**.